# Dojo Template for loop not looping inside html table

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates, dojo

I'm using a dojo widget to display some data through a dojo Template (which uses django templates). When using a for loop inside of an html  element, the loop only executes once and is unable to access the currently looping variable. However, the same loop outside of a table is able to loop as expected.

I'm not sure why this {% for %} loop will not work inside a  element but it works outside.

I've tried including "dojo/dom-construct", and have "dojox/dtl/tag/logic" included in my widget. My widget is currently defined as follows:

```js
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_OnDijitClickMixin",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/text!views/siteInfo/siteBatteries.html",
    "dijit/registry",
    "dojo/dom",

    "dojox/dtl/_DomTemplated",
    "dojox/dtl/tag/logic",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
],function(declare, _WidgetBase, _OnDijitClickMixin, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template, registry, dom, _DomTemplated){

    return declare([_WidgetBase, _OnDijitClickMixin, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, _DomTemplated], {
// WidgetLogic
});
});
```

Template:

```html
<div class="container" id="SiteOverviewController">
    {{ batteryList.length }}
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ObjectId</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for battery in batteryList %}
            <tr>
                <th>{{ battery.attributes.OBJECTID }}</th>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    END TABLE
    START DIV

    {% for battery in batteryList %}
        <div>{{ battery.attributes.OBJECTID }}</div>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

The output of the template above is as follows:

```html
<div class="container" id="SiteBatteryController" widgetid="SiteBatteryController" style="">
    4
    <table style="">
        <thead style="">
            <tr style="">
                <th style="">ObjectId</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="">
            <tr style="">
                <th style=""></th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    END TABLE
    START DIV
    <div style="">2225</div>
    <div style="">2226</div>
    <div style="">2227</div>
    <div style="">2228</div>
</div>
```

From the output you can see that the table only has one row with empty output:
`<tr style=""><th style=""></th></tr>` and loops only once when it should be looping 4 times (as seen with the  elements) and have data.

Comment: Not sure if it's the root if your issues, but you're using <th> instead of <td> (potentially, you might actually want to be using th here) - it's possible your templating language is just stripping any further headers within the row.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in dojo. I created a github issue in dojox for this, [see it here](https://github.com/dojo/dojox/issues/308)